# WiFi icon not showing on the menu bar and Internet not working (wifi or ethernet)?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

It used to work fine. There is no physical damage to the MacBook and the WiFi network I'd like to connect is is perfectly functional.

It will not connect to any WiFi network or ethernet-based networks.

How can I fix this?

Sometimes, the wifi status is in the top bar, but when I click on it, it says "No Wi-fi Hardware Installed".

Comment: What's the model and year of the MacBook?

Comment: any solution to this???

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you inadvertently disabled wi-fi and ethernet in system preferences > network?  If they are not listed in the left hand column of that window you can add them back by clicking the plus sign to 'create a new service' and then setup wi-fi and ethernet.  It's nothing more than picking them from the list of services and then clicking 'Apply'

Comment: I just tried to click on the plus sign, but there was no wifi option. There was only Ethernet, Firewire, PPPoE, 4 to 6, and Bluetooth PAN options.

Comment: There is also a checkbox called "Show Wi-Fi status in menu bar" that you may need to check.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually connect to WiFi using your Terminal (copy-paste following):

- Turn On Wi-Fi

  ```
  networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
  ```
- Find a network (you can skip this if you know the info already).

  ```
  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan
  ```
- Connect to the network

  ```
  networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN WIFI_PASSWORD
  ```

You can try this to turn it on with `sudo ifconfig en0 up`

If none of this worked:

Check under About this Mac for WiFi showing something like this:

[image: wifi]

Comment: It says that "You cannot set Wi-fi power because all AirPort network services are disabled."

Comment: ok, lets turn it on with  sudo ifconfig en1 up

Comment: heres the response: "ifconfig :interface en1 does not exist"

Comment: @Buscar웃 `sudo ifconfig en1 up` should be en0, no ?

Comment: sorry, you are right - en0 as zero

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the system isn't running in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201262) (`-x` arg in `nvram -p`).

If not, in *Terminal* or in single-mode run:

```
sudo networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

If you see an asterisk (*) next to your WiFi, it means the service is disabled. Enable it by:

```
networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled WiFi on
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Same for any other network services which are disabled. See also this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249796/22781).

Then restart your system to enable these services at startup.