# Cannot add wireless network in Mavericks in System Preferences

Tags: macos, wifi, vpn, system-settings

I accidentally deleted the wifi connection on my macbook pro (I went to System Preference > Network, i tried to delete a VPN but accidentally deleted the WIFI connection as well). Now if I add a WIFI again using the + sign, it does not gets added. The wifi sign the top bar shows a cross on it. I have restarted my system and used different logins but it id not adding the wifi again. I also also used different names but it did not work. I need this fix asap.

Comment: are you sure your network is available?

Comment: it is not about network, it is about installing the wifi adaptor I guess. Basically wifi should show up in the list of networks before it can be connected to an available network.

Comment: have you checked this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134727/wifi-icon-not-showing-on-the-menu-bar-and-internet-not-working-wifi-or-ethernet

Comment: That is helpful post but the problem in my case, if I add wifi using + sign, it does not get added. if I do it with any other type like thunderbolt, it does gets added.

Comment: you turned off the wifi, check in about this mac

Comment: In the other thread try the steps described in Buscars answer

Comment: Thank @Buscar웃 your answer on the other post was helpful but I have to carefully type the commands as I am on Windows now. Ok so I see Wifi has en1 interface. It says Network status Inactive. How will I activate it.

Comment: I tried `sudo ifconfig en1 up` and then the same command with `down` does seem to fix the problem. brb thx

Comment: you should be checking good answers so we do not sit here having them displayed as not done :)

Answer (score 3):

In Terminal type this command :

```
sudo ifconfig en1 up

sudo ifconfig en0 up
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, however I just want to share my solution for the problem, because the problem almost made me nuts and I hope my solution is simple enough and works so someone doesn't have to pull his/her hairs off.

This is my simple solution that worked (at least for me). :

- Goto System Preferences and then goto Network.
- When the Network screen appears, find the Location combo and delete all location that you find in there.
- Now you are left out with only one Location, that is 'Automatic'.
- Find the plus sign at the left bottom o Network screen, click it to add new  interface, when interface list appears, choose Wi-fi and click create.
- There, you should now see a Wi-fi interface added to the left hand side list.
- Click Apply to save.
- That's it, Hope this helps.

Comment: You solution may be the right one, which I cannot test unfortunately right now. But thanks for adding the answer. I have also added my own answer which at the time I forgot to post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - pressing the Plus sign and adding a missing Wi-Fi interface did nothing. I tried `sudo ifconfig en1 up` but it didn't work.

The reason was that Wi-Fi somehow became a part of Thunderbolt Bridge interface, even though during troubleshooting I tried deleting all interfaces including the Thunderbolt Bridge one.

Here is how I fixed the problem:

1. Go to System Preferences -> Network.
2. If you don't have a Thunderbolt Bridge interface on the right hand side, create one using the Plus button.
3. Press the Gear button -> Manage Virtual Interfaces.

[image]

4. Press the Edit (Pen) button.

[image]

5. If you have both Wi-Fi and Thunderbolt interfaces checked than that's it - go ahead and uncheck the Wi-Fi interface.

[image]

6. Press Done, Apply, and so on.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was sort of hidden. One of the connection on the left hand side has Wifi Interface selected **which was in fact NOT wife device**. You have to check all of the connection to find out the culprit. Detail is in the link below

[Fix Wifi Connection problem on Mac - Mac will not connect to wife](http://hammadk.com/cannot-add-wireless-network-on-mac-using-system-preferences/)